# Trying to access array returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, json

I thought I was doing this correct but this might be a total noob mistake.

Here is my JSON data

```
{
"rows": {
    "row1": {
        "divs": 7,
        "offset": 0,
        "colors": {
            "color1": "#003366",
            "color2": "#336699",
            "color3": "#3366CC",
            "color4": "#003399",
            "color5": "#000099",
            "color6": "#0000CC",
            "color7": "#000066"
        }
    },
    "row2": {
        "divs": 8,
        "offset": 11,
        "colors": {
            "color1": "#006666",
            "color2": "#006699",
            "color3": "#0099CC",
            "color4": "#0066CC",
            "color5": "#0033CC",
            "color6": "#0000FF",
            "color7": "#3333FF",
            "color8": "#333399"
        }
    },
    "row3": {
        "divs": 9,
        "offset": 22,
        "colors": {
            "color1": "#669999",
            "color2": "#009999",
            "color3": "#33CCCC",
            "color4": "#00CCFF",
            "color5": "#0099FF",
            "color6": "#0066FF",
            "color7": "#3366FF",
            "color8": "#3333CC",
            "color9": "#666699"
        }
    }
}
}
```

I saved it to a file and pushed it into an array like this

```
var colorPicker = []

$(function () {
$.getJSON("js/json/colorPicker.json", function (data) {
    colorPicker.push(data)
});
})
```

Now I am trying to access this array. 
I can get into it doing `colorPicker[0]`
That will return the whole object.

```
Object {rows: Object}
```

When I do `colorPicker[0].rows` it will return the 3 rows

```
Object {row1: Object, row2: Object, row3: Object}
```

But when I do `colorPicker[0][1]` shouldn't that give me just one the rows? 
I keep on getting undefined.

When I do `colorPicker[0].rows.row1` Then I can access my values from there. But if I want to use a for each loop it would be easier to do something like `colorPicker[0][1].divs`, wouldent it? Am I approaching this wrong?

Comment: `colorpicker[0].rows.row1`

Comment: `data` is of `Object` type

    Object {rows: Object}

To access the value of the Object you need to specify the key. If you will specify

    colorPicker[0]["row1"]

You will get you  result. Now, how to iterate the object? With Array you know that the keys are integers, so you change integers in the loop. Objects keys are a bit different, keys there you may get by

    var keys = Object.key(colorPicker[0]);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since its an object you cannot go by indexes 0,1,2, instead you need to give the name of the key, So if you want to iterate through all of the keys inside the object, you could do something like this :-

```
$.each(colorPicker[0]['rows'], function(key){
    console.log(colorPicker[0]['rows'][key]); // replace it with whatever you want to do with the row, key=row1/row2/row3
    console.log(colorPicker[0]['rows'][key].divs);
    //for getting all colors
    var temp = colorPicker[0]['rows'][key]["colors"];
    $.each(temp, function(key1){
        console.log(temp[key1]);
    });
});
```

Comment: Okay, no that did what I needed it to. What if I wanted to dig deeper and access the colors object as well?

Comment: Okay, I did that too console.log(data['rows'][key]['colors'])

Comment: yup, loop through the colours like that using $.each again, @Christian4423 does this work?

Comment: Wow. It's golden. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You've named each row by the string `"row1"`, `"row2"`, `"row3"`, etc.

To access them, you should actually use `colorPicker[0]["row1"]` or `colorPicker[0].row1` - but the first option can be done programmatically - in a loop.

I also think you're converting it incorrectly. Did you try [jQuery.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) instead?

Comment: The first one returns undefined still :/

Answer (score 0):

#### [Use a JSON formatter/validation tool to validate that your JSON is what you think it is.](https://www.jsoneditoronline.org/)

If you want array access you have to use an array: `"rows" : []` is an array, `"rows" : {}` is an object/map:

```
{
    "rows": [
        {
            "divs": 7,
            "offset": 0,
            "colors": {
                "color1": "#003366",
                "color2": "#336699",
                "color3": "#3366CC",
                "color4": "#003399",
                "color5": "#000099",
                "color6": "#0000CC",
                "color7": "#000066"
            }
        },
        {
            "divs": 8,
            "offset": 11,
            "colors": {
                "color1": "#006666",
                "color2": "#006699",
                "color3": "#0099CC",
                "color4": "#0066CC",
                "color5": "#0033CC",
                "color6": "#0000FF",
                "color7": "#3333FF",
                "color8": "#333399"
            }
        },
        {
            "divs": 9,
            "offset": 22,
            "colors": {
                "color1": "#669999",
                "color2": "#009999",
                "color3": "#33CCCC",
                "color4": "#00CCFF",
                "color5": "#0099FF",
                "color6": "#0066FF",
                "color7": "#3366FF",
                "color8": "#3333CC",
                "color9": "#666699"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```